# Nested loop with repeat

Tags: r, loops, nested-loops, repeat

I have this loop function

```
item <- function(item, iteration) {
  nrItem <- 0
  OKItem <- 0
  nrIteration <- 0
  repeat {
    nrIteration <- nrIteration + 1
    repeat {
      nrItem <- nrItem + 1
      A <- sample(c(0:1), size=1)
      OKItem <- OKItem + A
      if (nrItem == item) { 
        break
      }
    }
    return(OKItem)
    if (nrIteration == iteration){
      break
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to iterate over items and count number of OK items (its items that get 1 in iteration) and do it iteration times. Output should be number of OK items (approximately half of items should be OK in the end).

but I get only first iteration

Example

```
item(10,3)
[1] 6
```

But I would like to get something like this

```
item(10,3)
[1] 6
[2] 5
[3] 5
```